# What is a 2D float tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, torch, tensor

**Disclamer:** I know **nothing** about CNN and deep learning and I don't know [Torch](http://torch.ch/).

I'm using [SIFT](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html) for my object recognition application. I found this paper [Discriminative Learning of Deep Convolutional Feature Point Descriptors](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_iccv_2015/html/Simo-Serra_Discriminative_Learning_of_ICCV_2015_paper.html) which is particularly interesting because it's CNN based, which are more precise than classic image descripion methods (e.g. SIFT, SURF etc.), but (quoting the abstract):

> using the L2 distance during both training and testing we develop
>   128-D descriptors whose euclidean distances reflect patch similarity,
>   and which can be used as a drop-in replacement for any task involving
>   SIFT

Wow, that's fantastic: that means that we can continue to use any SIFT based approach but with more precise descriptors!

However, quoting the [github code repository](https://github.com/cvlab-epfl/deepdesc-release) README:

> Note the output will be a Nx128 2D float tensor where each row is a
>   descriptor.

Well, what is a "2D float tensor"? SIFT descriptors matrix is Nx128 floats, is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Oh well, that's embarrassing for me. Thanks @FranckDernoncourt

Comment: too many different terms for the same meaning in research…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2D float tensor = 2D float matrix.

FYI: [The meaning of tensors in the neural network community](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/181556/12359)

Answer (score 0):

This is a 2-d float tensor.

```
[[1.0,2.0],
 [3.0,4.0]]
```

This is still a 2-d float tensor, even if they have 3 items, and 3 rows!

```
[[1.0,2.0,3.0],
 [4.0,5.0,6.0],
 [7.0,5.0,6.0]]
```

The number of bracket is what matters.